# Excel VBA - Find _ or . in word then put word in seperate field

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a large list of cells that contain SQL within each cell.  I want to find any word with a `_` or `.` and then pull that word from the cell and put in adjacent cell.

There may be **2 or 10 words** that have `_` or `.`

Basically, I trying to identify all the [fields] within my SQL and create a list of them beside the actual SQL.

Thanks in advance for any assitance you can provide. **Excel 2007**

Comment: What have you tried so far? It might also help to include some example data. Do the cells contain multiple "words"? This should be pretty easy nest iteration over the range of cells, then use the `Split` string function on each cell's `.Value` to iterate the words in each cell.

Comment: SQL CODE 'CASE WHEN ABC.GH_IDF_ST_CD IN ('R','L') OR (ABC.DEF_FLS_ST_CD = 'L' AND ABC.GH_CLS_ST_CD > '9') OR (INSTR(UPPER(ABC.GH_IN_NAME),'REDO',1,1) > 0 AND FLAG.FLG_PARTA != '1') THEN 1 ELSE 0'

Comment: I have tried to pull snipits out but there are just to many variables.  I tried replaceing all thinks like and, or, like, upper, then, else and so on with a space.  Then tried text to columns.  I always end up with about 30 columns and something get screwed up and I loose characters.

Comment: what would you do with a word that contains `.` *and* `_` like `ABC.GH_IDF_ST_CD` in your example?

Comment: Basically if a word contains _ or .  I'm thinking I can do a find/replace and remove all the () characters with a space.  Then if the code finds a .  or _  it would go from [space] before and after to find whole [field].  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, I think:

```
Option Explicit
Sub PrintSQLFields()

Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim str As String
Dim i%
Dim possibleFields As Variant
Dim substr As Variant


Set rng = Range("A1:A10")    '## MODIFY AS NEEDED, but should be a single column

For Each r In rng.Cells
    i = 0
    str = r.Value
    'replace the parentheses
    str = Replace(str, "(", " ")
    str = Replace(str, ")", " ")

    'Split by space
    possibleFields = Split(str, " ")
    For Each substr In possibleFields

        'Check if the substring contains either "_" or "."
        If StrContains(CStr(substr), "_") Or StrContains(CStr(substr), ".") Then
            'print value to next adjacent cell
            i = i + 1
            r.Offset(0, i).Value = substr
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub

Function StrContains(str$, char$) As Boolean

    If InStr(1, str, char) Then StrContains = True

End Function
```

Comment: This is amazing, I guess I'm not at good at vba then I thought. The difference between pro and practice.  Thank you SOOO much.  Thanks works great

Comment: You're welcome! Please do mark this answer as "accepted" if it has resolved your problem.